# JBOSS 7.1.1 on Windows 8

Tags: java, netbeans, windows-8, jboss

Im trying to create new web application in NetBeans enviroment, using support of JBoss 7.1.1 server. After launching the app, web service says that web page is not responding. But its normaly working when I use Glassfish server. I think, that JBoss is not working properly on Windows 8. Do anyone have some advice for me please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: When you start up JBoss, what is output to the console? Any exceptions? Anything similar in the server logs?

Comment: Everything starts normally, no exception, no errors. I can copy the log for you here if you want to.

Comment: You mention both web service and web page? Do you mean the web page? If so, what does the browser come back with when you attempt to access the app?

Comment: Web page is not responding, nothing happens after launching the app. Netbeans launches my Chrome, but web page is not responding.

Comment: Do anyone have some advice for me?

Comment: Try copying your deployment to JBoss directly, start server and access the app in browser, all outside of NetBeans.